# moving indexPath.row to a label using addTarget: action: forControlEvents:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to move my `indexPath.row` to a different viewcontroller - `pageView` label. This is what I have tried:

```
[cell.nav addTarget:self action:@selector(naviguate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.nav.tag=indexPath.row;

-(void)naviguate:(id)sender {
    UIButton *theButton=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(names[theButton.tag]);
    pageView *secondViewController = [[pageView alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    secondViewController.name.text = names[theButton.tag];
}
```

Why is this not changing the label text on `pageView`. How should I do it?

---

Where the Logs string works fine.

---

## Edit for @danh

I have tried this:

```
-(void)naviguate:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         
                         [_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 569, _tableView.frame.size.width, _tableView.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender:self];
                     }];
    
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIButton *theButton=(UIButton *)sender;
    
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"link"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        pageView *controller = (pageView *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.name.text= names[theButton.tag];
    }
}
```

where it is being called by

```
[cell.nav addTarget:self action:@selector(naviguate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.nav.tag=indexPath.row;
```

But I am getting the error `[pageView topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[pageView topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Do you know why?

---

## 2nd attempt

with:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIButton *theButton=(UIButton *)sender;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"link"])
    {
        pageView *controller = (pageView *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.name.text= names[theButton.tag];
    }
}
```

I get the error `'-[ImagesTableViewController tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

WHich is crashing because of `names[theButton.tag]` How come?

Comment: Define "not working"? FYI - the term "not working" is one of the most useless statements a programmer can make. Provide details. What happens? What is logged? Have you used the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
pageView *secondViewController = [[pageView alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

creates a new view controller, then this line:

```
secondViewController.name.text = names[theButton.tag];
```

sets one of it's view's properties (which is wrong, because the view isn't loaded yet, and because it's ill-advised to mess around with another vc's views).  But that doesn't really matter, because this line:

```
}
```

destroys the newly allocated vc, which will never be heard from again.

The way to fix is either to use a segue from the starting view controller, and set properties of the destination in `prepareForSegue:`, or to push or present the secondViewController.  Either:

```
// if we're in a navigation controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:true];

// or, if there's no container
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:true completion:nil];
```

Remember, no matter how you decide to present secondViewController, don't try to set the state of one of it's subviews directly.  Instead, give it a property like `NSString *theStringMyLabelShouldShow`, and set that from the presenting vc.  The second VC can mess with it's own views in `viewWillAppear:`

```
self.name.text = self.theStringMyLabelShouldShow;
```

Comment: Excellent answer. (Voted). This would make a good answer to the 10,000 "Why can't I change another view controller's view" questions that pop up here.

Comment: The sender of that method is not a button.  Connect the segue between the two view controllers (not from the table view, but in IB by dragging between the status bars of the from and to vcs).  Then in the click handler for the button, you can performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:.  Then you can pass the button as the sender.